# What is the syntax of passing the entire array of struct pointers to a function?

Tags: c, struct, parameters

I'm really confused on what the correct syntax is to passing an array of struct pointers to a function? For the reason of being to be able to access each and every single one, e.g. BookList[0], BookList[5] or BookList[8].

Here is my struct and an array of pointers;

```
struct Book{
char Category[20];
int ID;
char BookName[40];
char Author[10];};


struct Book *BookList[10];
```

So lets say I create a new void function;

```
void ListBooks();
```

Now, how would the parameter syntax be? is it BookList[]? is it *BookList[10]; Apologies but I'm an extreme newbie, just trying to learn.

Comment: The syntax is: `UseYour(BookList[BegginerC_Book]);` and learn some C. Not from the YT videos

Comment: How about you try it? Make sure your compiler has all warnings and errors enabled -- it is NOT enough that the code compiles. Hint: `BookList` is the name of the variable you've declared, but you do not need that name in your function declaration at all; you need the name of the type.

Comment: The syntax is not that important. The [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) is very important. You need to understand what pointers and arrays are, and when exactly arrays become decayed to pointers (and what that entails). A book (or several chapters in it) is needed to explain that.

Comment: `void ListBooks(struct Book* BookList[]);` is one way to do it. `void ListBooks(struct Book** BookList);` is another way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formal array parameter of the function *ListBooks* should be either `struct Book **bookList` or `struct Book *bookList[]`. The latter is only syntactic sugar; in both cases only the address to the first element is passed to the function. This means that there is no way to tell the length of the array parameter inside the function. For this reason we also need to pass the length of the array as a second parameter. To summarize: Outside of function *ListBooks* your array *bookList* is an array of ten elements; inside *ListBooks* the formal parameter *bookList* is just a pointer (to a pointer to a struct).

When we pass the length of the array to *ListBooks* we don't want to repeat the value 10. Therefor it is convenient to define a length macro as shown in the code below.

```
#define LEN(array) (sizeof (array) / sizeof (array)[0])

struct Book {
    char Category[20];
    int ID;
    char BookName[40];
    char Author[10];
};

void ListBooks(struct Book *bookList[], int bookListLen)
{
    ...
}


int main(void)
{
    struct Book *bookList[10];

    ...
    ListBooks(bookList, LEN(bookList));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer need some explanation in English. Remember that OP is a newbie

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch OK, good suggestion. I have added some more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is more clear to use struct Book **bookList as the parameter.

Comment: It depends, and it is a tricky subject.